# Build ESRI addin with C++

Tags: c++, add-in

Is it possible to build an ESRI addin (.esriaddin) using C++? I see templates for .NET and C# only but perhaps there is a manual method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Addins are based on managed code (or Java), so you can develop them in managed C++/CLI, not in pure C++.